# invoke-parallel in Powershell - data sharing inside script with global variable

Tags: powershell

Using invoke-parallel in Powershell, I'm trying to get a list of hosts where a certain command works vs. does not.  How can I write to a global variable inside of invoke-parallel?

```
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message 'Password?'
$servers = get-content .\hosts.txt
$success = @()
$failure = @()

Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $servers -throttle 20 -runspaceTimeout 30 -ImportVariables -ScriptBlock {
    try 
    {
        $result = Invoke-Command $_ -Credential $creds -Authentication "Negotiate" -ErrorAction Stop {hostname} 
        $success += $result
    } 
    catch 
    {
        $failure += $_
    }
}

write-host $success
write-host $failure
```

Comment: Which command are you testing for? Why are you using Invoke-Command inside Invoke-Parallel? Can you instead check if the command/cmdlet exists? Or if the module/snap-in exists?

Comment: 1) Testing for "hostname" inside of invoke-command
2) i didn't see a way to pass in credentials to invoke-parallel
3) commandlet is working fine, i have dot sourced it before using

Comment: If not explicitly using the name of the parameter, the `ScriptBlock` must be in position 1, which is where you have `$_`.

Comment: Everything in this script is working correctly, except writing to $success or $failure inside the script.  I'm trying to write to a global variable to store results.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't have this module installed, so I can't test it. Have you tried storing the entire block into a variable? Like, `$Results = Invoke-Parallel ...` and then just outputting the data in the script block instead of storing it in its own variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Results = Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $servers -throttle 20 -runspaceTimeout 30 -ImportVariables -ScriptBlock {
    try 
    {
        $Output = Invoke-Command $_ -Credential $creds -Authentication "Negotiate" -ErrorAction Stop {hostname}
    } 
    catch 
    {
        $Output = $_
    }
    @($Output)
}
```

Comment: That sort of works.  Returns all data as a single string.  Parsing could be done afterwards, however still wondering if modifying a variable inside is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: I wrapped the data in parentheses to force it to an array. See if that changes anything.

Comment: No, I think invoke-parallel just concatenates all the output regardless. Doesn't seem to have changed anything. Thanks though.

Comment: Wait, I lied - it does seem to be in an array now.  Let me play around some more, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Final code sample for what I ended up using.

```
$username = "myuser"
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message 'Password?'
$servers = get-content .\hosts.txt

$Results = Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $servers -throttle 20 -runspaceTimeout 30 -ImportVariables -ScriptBlock {
    $arr = @{}
    try 
    {
        $Output = Invoke-Command $_ -Credential $creds -Authentication "Negotiate" {hostname} -ErrorAction Stop
        $arr[$_] = "successful"
    } 
    catch 
    {
        $arr[$_] = "failed"
    }
    $arr
}
$Results
```